# Accommodation booking date is overlapping

Tags: java

I have implemented isBookable() method based on below condition but isBookable() return true if arrival_date >=departure_date or departure_date<arrival_date
In short it`s allowing overlaping dates.

Condition:

> If accommodation is available for requested "arrival_date" and
> "departure_date" then isBookable method return true else return false.

```java
@Override
public boolean isBookable(Integer custId,Long accommodationId, Date arrival_date, Date departure_date) throws ParseException {
        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Rentability rentability=new Rentability();
        RentabilityDAO rdao=RentabilityDAOFactory.getInstance();
        List<Rentability> list=new ArrayList<Rentability>();
        
        list=rdao.getAllRentabilityByAccommodationId(accommodationId);
        
    //business logic    
    
    return;
        
}
```

Comment: Proper formatting of code snippets on this site: Either indent with 4 spaces, OR put three back-tick marks above and below. I fixed it for you on this Question.

Comment: The shown code does not contain any control logic, the most obvious one of which would be an `if`, nor the use of an appropriate date function. It also does not return anything. These issues are so elemental that thequestion leaves an impression that you want your homework done by others. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions to learn how to focus your question on the speicifc programming problem you encountered while trying yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reference

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will halp you..

```
public boolean isBookable(Integer custId,Long accommodationId, Date arrival_date, Date departure_date) throws ParseException {
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Rentability rentability=new Rentability();
    RentabilityDAO rdao=RentabilityDAOFactory.getInstance();
    List<Rentability> list=new ArrayList<Rentability>();
    
    
    list=rdao.getAllRentabilityByaccommodationId(accommodationId);
    int flag=0;
    
    if(list.isEmpty()){ 
        flag=1;
    }else{
        for(Rentability r:list){   //avoid overlap
            if(arrival_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getArrival_date()))>=0
                &&arrival_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getDeparture_date()))>=0
                &&departure_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getArrival_date()))>=0
                &&departure_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getDeparture_date()))>=0||
                arrival_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getArrival_date()))<=0
                &&arrival_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getDeparture_date()))<=0
                &&departure_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getArrival_date()))<=0
                &&departure_date.compareTo(sdf1.parse(r.getDeparture_date()))<=0)
                {
                flag=1;
            }
            else{
                flag=0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //business loging 
    check overlaping condition by flag status..
    return;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

## `LocalDate::isAfter`

Your are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

For date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

To compare, use `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`.

```
LocalDate arrival = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate departure = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) ;

boolean departureIsAfterArrival = departure.isAfter( arrival ) ;
```

A shorter way of saying "is same or later" is "is not before".

```
boolean departureIsSameOrLaterAsArrival = ( ! departure.isBefore( arrival ) ) ;
```

Your code:

> ("dd-MM-yyyy")

When exchanging date-time values as text, use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These formats are used by default in *java.time*.

For presentation to users, let *java.time* automatically localize using `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).